# Rails 3: How to ask questions to narrow down a set of data results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm new to rails and programming so I'm not really sure how to do this yet and I'd love if I could get a little.

I'd like to create entries for people that contain a set of data such as 'eye color' choice a) blue, b) brown, c) green, or d) other. And so on for 'hair color', and other attributes.

I'd like to ask the questions like "What color eyes?" with the choices a, b ,c, or d. Then after they answer the first question they get the second question, "what hair color?" and so on. After they answer all the questions they are given a set of results defined by the parameters they answered in the questions.

I'd really like to learn about how I'd go about making this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Agile Web Programming with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) is an excellent starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could simply create a form with all of the questions showing that they would fill out in-order.  This would probably be a good first step depending on just how new you are to learning rails and programming.  The rails guides are a great resource, for tutorial-based learning then http://railsforzombies.org/ is a great and short started, and for a more complete walkthrough then http://railstutorial.org/ is another good one.

Now, if you really want/need that sequence of questions as you describe, then check this Railscasts episode for creating a Multistep Form (aka wizard).  http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms.  Once you've got the form setup as you want it, you'll need to setup the actions after the submit to return the response as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate the links. The more I learn about rails the more I find that I a form would actually create new database entries, where I would like to narrow down already existing database entries according to defined parameters. Would I instead need to create form that searches the defined parameters?  such as this http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form

Answer (score 0):

Try the officail Rails guides. They are a good starting point:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/